# When adding second JOIN, the results look very different for numbers of first JOIN (difficulty combining two JOINS)

Tags: sql

I have such an issue, whenever I do one single JOIN for a query based on 2 common fields, in my case on Agency and Master Chain, the query works just fine and the numbers look exactly how they should be.

```
SELECT s.DEAGY AS 'AGENCY', l.cmschn AS 'MASTER_CHAIN', s.DECHN AS 'CHAIN', s.DESTR AS 'STORE_NUMBER', s.DEWEDT AS 'WK_ENDING',  
CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY ELSE 0 END AS  'OB_UNITS',
CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY * s.DERSP ELSE '0'END AS OB_BILLING,
CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY * s.DERPRC ELSE 0 END AS OB_MSRP 
  
INTO ##temp1
FROM REPIT.SMPDTA.SMPDTLM s
JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
ON s.DEAGY=l.CMAGY AND s.DECHN=l.CMCHN

where s.DEWEDT = 20210807 AND s.DEAGY=10 AND s.DECHN='WM'

SELECT AGENCY, MASTER_CHAIN, CHAIN, STORE_NUMBER, WK_ENDING,
SUM(OB_UNITS) as OB_UNITS, 
SUM(OB_BILLING) as OB_BILLING,
SUM(OB_MSRP) as OB_MSRP

FROM ##temp1
WHERE WK_ENDING = 20210807
GROUP BY AGENCY, MASTER_CHAIN, CHAIN, STORE_NUMBER, WK_ENDING
ORDER BY STORE_NUMBER;
```

However, when I try to add one more join (in order to combine it with another table) it basically destroys everything and numbers look completely off. I am trying to join my 2 table on such fields as Agency, Chain, Store#, WeekEndingDate and ItemLevel.

JOIN LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM sm
ON s.DEAGY=sm.DEAGY AND s.DECHN=sm.DECHN AND s.DESTR=sm.DESTR AND s.DEWEDT=sm.DEWEDT AND s.DEITM#=sm.DEITM#

I have never seen such a difference after adding a second JOIN.

If someone may have any ideas, will be greatly appreciated.

Desired result (I want to have the same result for my calculations
SUM(OB_UNITS) as OB_UNITS,
SUM(OB_BILLING) as OB_BILLING,
SUM(OB_MSRP) as OB_MSRP
as I had them before my 2nd JOIN.

Those numbers are okay after 1st JOIN, however when add a 2nd JOIN (join a different table) on other columns, the system somehow throws everything off and they are completly wrong.

So desired result is to add a second join and connect it somehow so that the numbers for those 3 calculations are as they were before the 2nd JOIN.

[Results after 1st JOIN  - what I want to have after 2nd JOIN as well (desired result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxTzk.png)

That's what I get after the 2nd JOIN (for some reasons numbers are completly off)

[Results after 2nd JOIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mPqx.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help.

Comment: @Stu I have provided the code, it is pretty minimal, just the essential rows.  I have provided the desired result description as thoroughly as I could.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the very bad numbers due to a Cartesian result.  If the secondary table join has multiple rows for whatever the join condition IS, that will multiply your results.  To resolve, pre-query your second table on DISTINCT instances of the fields you are joining again.  This will make sure it can only match up with a single record from the primary leaving those original values as-is.

Without seeing the origin of the data (even samples), its a little harder to get a final answer.  Please consider providing in the future questions.  Just edit your original question and provide.

So, I forgot to put the SUM() for the aggregates that you appeared to want.  However, one additional point. Your `CASE` condition is including 2 of the 3 conditions in the where clause (DEAGY and DECHN), but you only care about the amounts when DEIO = 'O', so why not just add that to the where clause as well since those are the only numbers that are being returned anyhow.  A more simplified version of the query below with said modifications

Finally, with the join to the `LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM` table and joined on the same 5 columns of your original join, what else does that give you.  It appears to be a wasted effort for fields you already have .. UNLESS there is some other field on that table that you want to pull out, such as a lookup name/contact or whatever else.  Then that column would need to be added to that subquery, and the column pulled to your outer query final results.

Again, this is why its important to show where all the pieces are for your query, sample data AND your expected output results.  Anyhow, here is the revised query.

```
SELECT 
        s.DEAGY AGENCY, 
        l.cmschn MASTER_CHAIN, 
        s.DECHN CHAIN, 
        s.DESTR STORE_NUMBER, 
        s.DEWEDT WK_ENDING,
        sum( s.DEQTY ) OB_UNITS,
        sum( s.DEQTY * s.DERSP ) OB_BILLING,
        sum( s.DEQTY * s.DERPRC ) OB_MSRP 
    INTO 
        ##temp1
    FROM 
        REPIT.SMPDTA.SMPDTLM s
            JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
                ON s.DEAGY = l.CMAGY 
                AND s.DECHN = l.CMCHN

            JOIN 
            ( select distinct 
                        DEAGY,
                        DECHN,
                        DESTR,
                        DEWEDT,
                        DEITM#
                from
                    LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM ) sm
                ON s.DEAGY=sm.DEAGY 
                AND s.DECHN=sm.DECHN 
                AND s.DESTR=sm.DESTR 
                AND s.DEWEDT=sm.DEWEDT 
                AND s.DEITM#=sm.DEITM#
    where 
            s.DEWEDT = 20210807 
        AND s.DEAGY = 10 
        AND s.DECHN = 'WM'
        AND s.DEIO = 'O'
    group by 
        s.DEAGY, 
        l.cmschn, 
        s.DECHN, 
        s.DESTR, 
        s.DEWEDT
```

Comment: thank you for your help. For some reason I receive an error "DEQTY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." and later the same with "DERSP", "DERPSR"... when I group by all of them, i do receive a result but unfortunately it is wrong, not what i needed.

Comment: @JeremyU, revised several parts to answer... please re-read full context for changes.